# How can I get numbers of columns in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get numbers of columns in repeater.

```
int columnsCount = rp.Items.Count;
```

This returns 1 but I have 4 columns.

Comment: Why do you assume that Repeater has a column-count property? Repeater is not a Table or GridView.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean rows (items) instead of columns?

Answer (score 4):

A repeater has no notion of columns. You can consider it as a simple `foreach` loop in your view. When you query `rp.Items.Count` this returns the number of rows you have in the dataset that this repeater is bound to.

Comment: hi,can you give me an example?

Comment: @senzacionale, an example of what? It's up to you to show your repeater code and explain what you need because as I said a repeater has no notion of columns, only rows, so if you are asking how to get the number of columns in a repeater then I am answering: you can't.

Comment: @senzacionale, sorry, a `foreach` loops through items, no columns. A repeater is not a table or a `GridView` which has notion of columns.

Comment: foreach (var value in rp.Items)
            {
                count ++;
            }

Comment: @senzacionale, that's because you shouldn't be using a repeater if you need columns. You probably didn't understand my answer. In your `foreach` you are simply looping through the rows and because you probably have 1 row you get 1. So if you need columns don't use a repeater (which is a simple `foreach`).

Comment: @senzacionale, is it really so difficult for you to understand that a repeater has no notion of columns? I don't know how to say it with other words for you to understand. Take a look at the [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) component if you need columns.